# Trying to solve recurrence $T(n)=3T(n/3) + 3$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence without using the Master Theorem:

$$T(1)=1;$$

$$T(n)=3T(n/3) + 3$$

---

My attempt:

$T(n) = 3T(n/3) + 3$

$ = 3(3T(n/9) n/3)) + 3)$

$ = 9T(n/9) + 9$

$ = 9(3T(n/27 + n/9)) +9$

$ = 27T(n/27) + 9$

$ ...$

I know this is wrong but I'm stuck here. Thanks.

Comment: Why the second line is $3(3T(n/9) n/3)) + 3)$ and not $3(3T(n/3)+3)+3$?

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to figure out how to do this

Comment: You must replace $k$ times the recurrence you have and see what should be $k$ in order to stop the recurrence and use $T(1)=1$. So, if $k=3$ $T(n)=3T(n/3)+3=3(3T(n/3^2)+3)+3=3(3(3T(n/3^3)+3)+3)+3=3^3T(n/3^3)+3+3^2+3^3$..so, do it in general for $k$ and the geometric sum will be helpful.

Comment: I see. so what would Theta class would that be then? Theta(nlogn)?

Comment: What expression do you have at the end? If you guess is that complexity, try to prove it by induction.

Answer (score 1):

A change of argument turns this into a linear difference equation with constant coefficients. Let $n=3^k$. Then
$$T(n)=T\left(3^k\right)=a_k=3T(n/3)+3=3T\left(3^{k-1}\right)+3=3a_{k-1}+3$$
The solution to the homogeneous equation, $a_k=3a_{k-1}$ is $a_k=C\cdot3^k$ and there is a constant solution, $a_k=-3/2$ to the actual equation. Thus the general solution is
$$a_k=C\cdot3^k-\frac32$$
Applying the initial condition, $T(1)=a_0=C-3/2=1$, we have
$$a_k=T(3^k)=\frac52\cdot3^k-\frac32$$
So $T(n)=\frac52n-\frac32$, for $n$ a power of $3$. For other $n$ we don't have an initial condition.

Answer (score 1):

$$T(n)=3T\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)+3=3\left(3T\left(\frac{n}{3^2}\right)+3\right)+3=3^2T\left(\frac{n}{3^2}\right)+3^2+3$$Continuing so on.......
$$T(n)=3^kT\left(\frac{n}{3^k}\right)+3^k+3^{k-1}+..........+3^2+3\tag{1.}$$
Let $n=3^k$ then $T\left(\frac{n}{3^k}\right)=T(1)=1$ ,putting this in eq (1) :-
$$T(n)=3+3^2+3^3+...........+3^k+3^k=\frac{3(3^k-1)}{2}+3^k=\frac{3(n-1)}{2}+n=5\frac{n}{2}-\frac{3}{2}$$
i.e.
$$T(n)=\theta(n)$$

Comment: Perfect!!! thank you  Mayank.

Answer (score 0):

Writing out the first few terms, we get:

$$T(1) =1, T(3) = 6, T(9) = 21, T(27) = 66, T(81) = 201$$

Using this, we can see that $T(n) \approx2n$, so we make the ansatz that $T(n) = an + b$

Applying this to the recurrence relation gives us:
$$\begin{align*}an + b &= 3\left(a\frac{n}{3} + b\right) + 3\\an + b &= an + 3b + 3\\2b &= -3\\b &= \frac{-3}{2}\end{align*}$$

Finally, applying the boundary condition $T(1) = 1$:
$$\begin{align*}a + b &= 1\\a -\frac{3}{2} &= 1\\a &= \frac{5}{2}\end{align*}$$

Hence:

$$T(n) = \frac{5}{2}n - \frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

This recurrence only makes sense when repeatedly dividing $n$ by three eventually yields 1; that is, when $n$ is a power of three.  So let's start by assuming that $n=3^m$.  Then we may restate the problem as:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
T(3^0)&=&1 \\
T(3^m)&=&3T(3^{m}/3)+3 &=& 3T(3^{m-1})+3
\end{eqnarray}
$$
or
$$T(3^m)-3T(3^{m-1})-3=0$$
I'll point out that this is an order 1 linear recurrence relation in $m$, and that dictates that form of the result.  But instead of just pulling a formula out of thin air and solving for some coefficients, I'll demonstrate a method to actually derive the formula: using ordinary generating functions.

Let $f(x)=T(3^0)+T(3^1)x+T(3^2)x^2+\cdots$ be the ordinary generating function for the sequence $\{T(3^m)\}$.  We want to combine some multiples of this power series so that the the coefficients of the combination will satisfy the recurrence relation.  To do this, we calculate:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=&T(3^0)&+&T(3^1)x&+&T(3^2)x^2&+&T(3^4)x^3&+&\cdots \\
-3xf(x)&=&0&-&3T(3^0)x&-&3T(3^1)x^2&-&3T(3^2)x^3&+&\cdots \\
\frac{-3}{1-x}&=&-3&-&3x&-&3x^2&-&3x^3&+&\cdots \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Ok, I'll admit I did pull that last formula (for an infinite geometric series) out of thin air.  Adding these together, we have:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)-3xf(x)-\frac{3}{1-x} &=& -3 + T(3^0)&+&[T(3^1)-3T(3^0)-3]x&+&[T(3^2)-3T(3^1)-3]x^2&+&\cdots \\
&=& -2 &+& [0]x &+& [0]x^2 &+&\cdots
\end{eqnarray}
$$
So that $$
\begin{eqnarray}
[1-3x]f(x)&=&-2 +\frac{3}{1-x} \\
f(x)&=&\frac{-2}{1-3x}+\frac{3}{(1-x)(1-3x)} \\
&=&\frac{-2}{1-3x}-\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{1-x}+\frac{\frac{9}{2}}{1-3x} & \textrm{(partial fraction decomposition)} \\
&=&\frac{\frac{5}{2}}{1-3x}-\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{1-x} \\
&=&[\frac{5}{2}-\frac{3}{2}]+[\frac{5}{2}\cdot 3^1-\frac{3}{2}\cdot1^1]x+[\frac{5}{2}\cdot3^2-\frac{3}{2}\cdot1^2]x^2+\cdots
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Matching coefficients yields
$$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
T(3^m) &=& \frac{5}{2}\cdot3^m-\frac{3}{2} \\
T(n) &=& \frac{5}{2}n-\frac{3}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
$$